# Should I refactor loops into more descriptive methods?

Tags: loops, refactoring

I am currently writing some Javascript code, although this question isn't javascript specific, and I realize that I have loops everywhere(exaggerating). I try to make local variables for loops to make them more readable trying to stay away from `array[i][j]` kind of notations but I was wondering if I should refactor them into descriptively named methods?

This questions is purely for discussion for me to learn, and isn't specific to the situation I'm in right now. How much readability is enough, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

With all things...it depends.

Readability is the driving goal so if you have a large block of code with lots of loops, then perhaps it should be refactored.

I don't know if extracting the loops is always the best place.  I would perhaps factor out a piece of code that does some separate "unit".  Why are you looping?  Are you initialing variables? Are you searching for a specific element?  If so, that is what you should extract.

Comment: it is mostly looking for an element in an array.. i was thinking along the lines of refactoring into a ```if(inArray)``` kind of but a more descriptively named function.